# Make img fill entire height

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the image on the left to take up the entire height no matter how much content is on the right (see screenshot).

[image]

You'll have to make the viewport around 850px or less to see what I'm talking about.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.item-1 {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item-1-direct-child {
  min-height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 187px;
}

.item-2 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 75%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item-2-direct-child {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.button-container>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">
    <div class="item-1-direct-child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="item-2-direct-child">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
      </span>
      <div class="button-container">
        <a>
          <button>
          Button
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define *"entire height"*. Entire height of what? Of the containing element which height is dictated by the text content  length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct CSS, but you are applying it wrong.

Images can either be set as an `<img>` tag **or** as a CSS `background-image`.  Your CSS is trying to set a background image for an image element, which makes no sense.

Instead, remove the `<img>` tag and the CSS for it.  Just use this CSS

```css
.side-image-bg {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And add that class to the sidebar element.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.item-1 {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item-1-direct-child {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.side-image-bg {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.item-2 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 75%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item-2-direct-child {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.button-container > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">
    <div class="item-1-direct-child side-image-bg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="item-2-direct-child">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
      </span>
      <div class="button-container">
        <a>
          <button>
          Button
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a side note, you have this code:

```html
<a>
  <button>
  Button
  </button>
</a>
```

Which is a button inside of a link.  This is invalid HTML, and it makes no sense. An interactive element cannot be inside of another interactive element.  An `<a>` is for linking to another document, and a `<button>` is for either doing some action or submitting a form. You need to pick which one needs to happen here.

Comment: The fact that the OP used an image element (`img`) while also defining CSS properties for a background image, has no connection to the problem, which has to do with empty space in a container.

Comment: Also, being that the OP doesn't say whether the image represents content or is solely for decorative purposes, removing the image from the HTML and going with the CSS background image, is speculative and premature. If the image represents content, this solution is semantically deficient, as the `img` should stay and the CSS properties should go. Vice versa is the image for decoration.

Comment: Sorry, why remove the component's semantic `<img>` from the HTML? Just for the sake of `background-size: cover;`? `object-fit` can achieve the same effect for IMG as well.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I figure the image can be displayed in one of two ways, so I took a guess at the one that was trying to be achieved here. Perhaps I'm wrong and another answer that relies more heavily on an `<img>` tag. I tried to get that to behave the same as this but I was not able to get it to happen, at least not as quickly as I was with the background image approach. This is just an option for the question-asker to conciser, if another answer is better or more appropriate, that's entirely OK. Please submit an answer using your suggested solution if you feel that might be better.

Comment: Thanks all for your input! Super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the CSS:
changed `.item-1` to create a container to contain the image and in the `.item-1-direct-child,` `height: 100%;` and added flex to stretch its children vertically.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 25%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1-direct-child {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.item-2 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 75%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item-2-direct-child {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.button-container > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">
    <div class="item-1-direct-child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="item-2-direct-child">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
      </span>
      <div class="button-container">
        <a>
          <button>
          Button
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

just set height to 100vh

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" height="100vh">
```